# Μy little finger is too weak to play guitar

Tags: acoustic-guitar, fingering

I am learning guitar, but my little finger is too weak to play. For example, if I play a chromatic scale in first position and my first three fingers are in the right place, it feels extremely hard to put my little finger on the string, and my little finger seems in a very strange shape when I force it to press the string.

How can I practice the little finger? I really want to play guitar

Comment: The great Django Reinhardt figured out a way to become one of the world's most respected guitarists even though he had limited use of only two fingers on his fretting hand. Let this be an inspiration. I am fully confident you will learn how to do this. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I used to have the same problem on violin: my pinky started trembling violently when I tried holding a string down with it for more than a few seconds. Here are a few exercises I’ve used to increase the strength in my third and fourth fingers to the point where I have few issues playing music with them.

First is an exercise I learned after spraining my thumb. For each finger, touch your thumb to the fingertip. Squeeze. Repeat 2-3 times, with 10-30 seconds per finger.

Get a putty or sand filled grip ball such as is used by mountain climbers to work on hand strength. They usually come with a sheet of exercises you can try. There’s other types oh hand exercisers as well, but I like the balls because they are more ergonomic for a larger range of hand sizes.

In daily life: Think about using the pinky more. If you’ve got something to do that takes finger muscle, think about strength from the pinky and third finger, not just the index and middle fingers. Do things like spending 10 seconds gripping your computer mouse hard with all fingers every time you sit at your computer, or picking up your coffee mug using your third and fourth fingers instead of your index and middle fingers. Just add in using those muscles even when you don’t need to.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to leave the other three fingers in place on the frets, pressing down the strings, while you press the fourth fret note down. Mostly, you need to only press the note you're playing, certainly as a newbie. Later, when playing legato, and using pull-offs, you will probably need two fingers pressing simultaneously, but for now, release maybe the index and middle fingers while you press the pinky.

If you feel you have to leave everything on, it's possible further up the fingerboard, try from fret 5-8, but then another potential problem occurs, whereby the strings may be harder to press down, due to the action being higher.